# Cant get service reference for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created  a simple WCF service and hosted in it IIS at the location http://localhost/EssentialWCFIISService/service.svc

If I open this url in a web browser the service screen shows up fine and gives me this address for using the svcutil.exe file on - http://localhost/EssentialWCFIISService/service.svc?wsdl

So I then created a basic client application and clicked Add Service Reference and put that address into the dialog that appeared. However I am getting the following error:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost/EssentialWCFIISService/service.svc?wsdl'. Content
>   Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://localhost/EssentialWCFIISService/service.svc?wsdl.  The client
>   and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an
>   error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.. If the service is defined in the current
>   solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference
>   again.

From googling around I found several others with this problem and people the advice often says something along the lines of 'change the client's bindings to match the server's bindings'.....however I am not even at that stage, I have no bindings at all in my client as it is an empty project. Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: Do you have a binding and bindingCongifuration specified for the end point in your (WCF) web.config? Post your config; a lot of times these are just problems in your config file.

Comment: Found the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213956/svcutil-problem-with-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis-7-5

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the `?wsdl` when you add the service reference.